# Перенаправить вывод в тестовый файл

Tags: python

как сохранить данные которые выводятся в командную строку в формат txt

```
#Импорт XML файлов
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET




def parseXML(xml_file):
    tree=ET.ElementTree(file=xml_file)
    print(tree.getroot())
    root=tree.getroot()
    print("tag=%s, attrib=%s" % (root.tag, root.attrib))

    for child in root:
        print('child tag',child.tag, child.attrib)
        if child.tag == "appointment":
            for step_child in child:
                print(step_child.tag)

    for child in root.iter('BasicBlock'):
        for BasicBlock  in child.iter('BasicBlock'):
            print('BasicBlock', child.tag, child.attrib)
                                                                                                      #Выводит тег Data
    for child in root.iter('data'):
        for data in child.iter('data'):
            print('data', child.tag, child.attrib)


    for child in root.iter('ExplicitLink'):
         for ExplicitLink in child.iter('ExplicitLink'):
          print('ExplicitLink', child.tag, child.attrib)

    a = []
    f = open('parse.txt', 'w')
    for item in a:
        f.write(item)
    f.close()


path_to_program = r"C:\Users\Name PC\Desktop\Prractic"
path_to_XML = os.path.join(path_to_program, 'sss.xcos')


parseXML(path_to_XML)
```

Comment: `python yourscript.py > file.txt`.

Comment: а в какую часть кода нужно вставить это ?